# Can't get Inputsream from HTTPS URL - Connection timeout (ConnectException)

Tags: java, inputstream, connect

I intend to write a method to download images. All implementations failed so far, so I boiled it down to the code that produces the error and removed everything else, so the code just shows the important parts. The point is: the getinputstream() method causes a connection error when I use a HTTPS URL. How can I circumvent that? Could it be because of certificates? I'm just surprised that similar code I used in C# worked, but Java needs to circumvent certificates for HTTPS connections?

```
public static void img_DL(String s) throws IOException {

URL url = new URL(s);
InputStream inputStream;
String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36";
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
inputStream = con.getInputStream();
inputStream.close();
}
```

Here the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at application.Img.img_DL(Img.java:48)
at application.FXMLController.download_img(FXMLController.java:215)
... 58 more
```

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: Just added the stack trace of the part with the connection timeout.

Comment: To me it looks like the remote server is just timing out, can you give the problematic url also?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can check the details of the exception.
2. Run by setting -Djavax.net.debug=all to debug the error. See
   [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)
3. In case of timeout, check timeout settings. You may increase timeout by setting the system property.

   System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout", "10000");

Comment: I just added a stacktrace to the question.